# CSS percentage height has no effect

Tags: html, css, size, overflow

I have some heading and content HTML wrapped in a container like this:

```
<div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        Heading
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

I explicitly set the height of the parent element, `.panel`, and the child element,`.panel-body`:

```
.panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
.panel-body {
    height: 10%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But the child `.panel-body` height seems to ignore the CSS `height` rule, because it just grows arbitrarily with its content!  You can see the behavior at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RWPQD/).  Why does this happen?

It's important for me to have percent-calculated height *and* scrollable overflow on the `.panel-body`.  Is this possible?

(For reference, [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/RWPQD/1/) is the behavior I'm looking for, but with height calculated by `em` instead of `%`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

1. - Add a container
2. - Give it height 100%
3. - Add min-height to the panel container

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        Heading
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
        Body<br></br>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{height:100%;}

.container {
    height:100%;
}

.panel{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;   
}

.panel-body {
    height: 20%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

* {
    /* for box visibility */
    border: 1px dashed grey !important;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 5px !important;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/RWPQD/11/

**Ps.** I set the height of .panel-body at 20%, but you can change it accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks!  I'm assuming the `height` must be set with percentages all the way up the document tree for this to work.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes but you can still set the height in px if you want a fixed layout obviously. I'd assume you want to use this approach in order to develop a responsive site, right? :)

Comment: I'm trying to hammer out a fullscreen app with bootstrap.  Hence, the HTML/CSS height mechanism is an important thing for me to understand.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

the parent tag should have a known height, in your case `<panel>` does have a known height but for some reason it's parent doesnt have a specific height, add this in your css:

```
html, body { 
   height: 100%; 
   width: 100%;
 }
```

not sure if it is the best but i think it works